# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" в cron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вылезает ошибка. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>   Цитата

Модуль: /node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js

Код ошибочной строки:

> source = this.source.replace(/[a-z]{1,3}/ig, function(alias) {

Код функции:

```js
 _parse: function() {
  var aliases = CronTime.aliases,
  source = this.source.replace(/[a-z]{1,3}/ig, function(alias) {
   alias = alias.toLowerCase();

   if (alias in aliases) {
    return aliases[alias];
   }

   throw new Error('Unknown alias: ' + alias);
  }),
  split = source.replace(/^\s\s*|\s\s*$/g, '').split(/\s+/),
  cur, i = 0,
  len = timeUnits.length;

  for (; i < timeUnits.length; i++) {
   // If the split source string doesn't contain all digits,
   // assume defaults for first n missing digits.
   // This adds support for 5-digit standard cron syntax
   cur = split[i - (len - split.length)] || CronTime.parseDefaults[i];
   this._parseField(cur, timeUnits[i], CronTime.constraints[i]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Сделайте перед строкой с ошибкой вывод в консоль `console.log(this.source);` и посмотрите, что там содержится. Думаю, должна быть строка чтобы ошибки не было.

Comment: а где в вашем обьекте вы инициализируете поле source ?

Comment: что это за модуль и как он используется?

Comment: В 99.99% случаев проблема не в стороннем модуле, а в том, как вы его используете. Поэтому вместо кода чужого модуля добавьте в вопрос код, его использующий.